# Second php file can't find Session started in first file

Tags: javascript, php, session

I can't get the php $_SESSION variable to work the way I want it to. I've got two files. The first one setting the variable:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    $_SESSION['authenticated'] = "yes";
    echo json_encode('Authenticated successfully.');
?>
```

and a second one trying to retrieve it:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    print '<pre>';
    var_dump($_SESSION['authenticated']);
    print '</pre>';
?>
```

But the second file always prints `NULL` when it should print `"Yes"` and a new error is recorded in the server's log:

```
[Thu Sep 22 12:52:47.763114 2016] [:error] [pid 26644] [client <ip_here>] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: authenticated in <Second_file> on line 5, referer: <client_url_here>
```

*Both files are accessed by AJAX calls from JavaScript.*

The AJAX code for file 1 works as following:

```
$.ajax({
        url: corrDomain + '/auth.php', //Path and name of file #1. It's correct and working.
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            //This part is excluded in the above php code for simplification. It's guaranteed to work.
            username: username, 
            password: password,
            action: 'init'
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
          //Check if data contains the right information, then call function for file #2.
        },
        error: function(){
          //Something went wrong
        }
    });
```

When that code gets thumbs up from the php, that the user is authorized the following code will be run for file #2:

```
$.ajax({
    url: path + '/getProducts.php', //Also correct and working.
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        products.push(data);
        orderProductIds();

        //Update col 1 + 2;
        updateOrders('reload');

        //Set interval of updating col 1.
        setInterval(function(){
            updateOrders('update');
        }, 10000);
    },
    error: function(){          
        alert('Something went wrong.');
    }
});
```

---

UPDATE: I added `session_name();` as the first row in all my php files. The session now works if I open each file in the browser but not if I access them via AJAX. So the problem still persists, but maybe this can help you help me.

---

UPDATE #2: In Chrome's web inspector I can see that both files are returning Session Cookie ids, but they have different values. See screenshots.
[image]

[image]

---

UPDATE #3: I've researched and found that php sessions isn't possible when using PhoneGap, even though I'm requesting the php file via jQuery AJAX. Can someone confirm this?

Comment: Are you sure, you're accessing the first file first within one session?

Comment: It's not the first file I'm accessing through AJAX on page load, but it is the first one involving sessions.

Comment: post your ajax code. are you accounting for the "a" in ajax properly or is it possible you're hitting the getter page before the setter?

Comment: I've added the AJAX code to the question. The second file is not requested until the first one has correctly authorized the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you also start the session `session_start();` on the page which makes the AJAX calls

**EDIT**

A not preferable but maybe usefull method is to send the session_id with each ajax request to use more like a token.

The first PHP-script:

```
session_start();
echo json_encode([
    'message' => 'Session started',
    'session_id' => session_id()
]);
exit();
```

Store the received id in a javascript-variable:

```
var session_id;

$.ajax({
    ...
    success: function(data) {
        session_id = data.session_id;
    }
    ...
}
```

After that send the session_id along with each AJAX-request:

```
var data = {session_id: session_id, ... };

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "server.php",
    data: data,
    success: function(data) {

    }
});
```

Instead of the session_id you can generate a random token instead to send along with each request.

Comment: I'm doing the AJAX calls from a JS file loaded from html. Should I really add session_start(); to a client side file?

Comment: Everything will be packeted by Phonegap so I can't use php files other than via AJAX.

Comment: No not the clientside, i meant at the beginning of the serverside script which loads the html-page. But i understand you don't have that option, since your app is a phonegap application which calls a php script through ajax?

Comment: Are you sure cookies are enabled in your phonegap app?

Comment: Right now I'm running the page as a local folder on my computer. I haven't tried the page in Phonegap yet, but I can't see how that can be any different.

Comment: Can you try to use `exit();` at the end of each php script? In some cases this solves header issues

Comment: After adding `exit();` it's still printing null.

Comment: I'm not sure the problem is with PhoneGap because you have this problem also in Chrome. It looks like something with the cookies isn't configured correctly, either in the browser or on the server. Check if `session.use_cookies` is enabled on the server: [ini.session.use-cookies](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-cookies).

Comment: Another option would be: after the first ajax-call, to store the sessionid in a javascript variable. And after that, send the sessionid allong with each ajax request (like `data: {session_id: session_id, ...}`). But it's not a preferred solution.

Comment: Well, I've only got this problem when using AJAX. It works perfectly when calling the files in browser.

Comment: Can you tell me more about that sending session id with request idea? Or is it better to ditch sessions all together and change to a token based system?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123973/discussion-between-9focuspoints-and-cumul).